# How to split a vector into three variables in C++

Tags: c++

In Python the following expression splits the list `a` into the three variables `x,y,z`:

```py
a = [2,5,7]
(x,y,z) = a
```

Is there anything similar in C++? I've tried writing the following code but it does not works:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

int main() {
   int a[] = {3, 5, 7};
   int x,y,z;

   (x,y,z) = a;
}
```

Compiler fails with the following error:

```
error: assigning to 'int' from incompatible type 'int [3]'
    (x, y, z) = arr;
```

Comment: `int x=a[0], y=a[1], z=a[2];` is my favorite. Easy to read and understand.

Comment: Do you want x, y, and z to be references to the elements of a, or copies?

Comment: @Bathsheba just copies

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use *structured bindings* starting from C++17, like so:

```
std::tuple<int, int, int> a{ 1, 2, 3  };

auto [x, y, z] = a;
```

See: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/structured_binding

Pre-C++17 you can use `std::tie`, like so:

```
std::tuple<int, int, int> a{ 1, 2, 3  };

int x, y, z;
std::tie(x, y, z) = a;
```

See https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/tie

If it has to be something other than `std::tuple` or `std::pair`, you'll have to assign the variables manually:

```
x = a[0]; y = a[1]; x = a[2];
```

Comment: Does `std::tie` also works with vectors or just with tuples?

Comment: Just with `tuple`s, I'm afraid :( What you have there in your example is not a `vector` either, it's an array. If it has to be a `vector`, you can only do `x = a[0]; y = a[1]; x = a[2];` as far as I'm aware

Comment: It also works with `std::array`. The number of elements needs to be known at compile time which is not the case for a `std::vector`.

Answer (score 5):

The following works (C++17+):

```
int main() {
    int a[] = {3, 5, 7};
    auto [x, y, z] = a;
}
```

This will create copies of the values; to create references instead, use

```
…
auto& [x, y, z] = a;
```

Comment: Yeah, but i'm using c++11...

Comment: @beep Then you’re out of luck. But see the other answer for a workaround.

Answer (score 1):

I always have a slight issue with "I come from programming language X and I want to do the same in language Y". Each language has different philosophies and you would do well to understand those. C++ is typed, has a lot of compile time checking and its very important to understand scopes and their influence on lifetime of objects (when are destructors called).
So my advice is : if you want to do C++ learn C++ and kind of forget how you did things in Python

Having said that:

```
#include <iostream>

// best be explicit, define your own type! (or use one from a library)
struct vec_t
{
    int x;
    int y;
    int z;
};

int main()
{
    vec_t vec{ 1,2,3 };

    // no need to split, you can be explicit    
    std::cout << vec.x << "\n";
    std::cout << vec.y << "\n";
    std::cout << vec.z << "\n";

    // or you can use named bindings, but gain is minimal imo
    auto [x, y, z] = vec;

    std::cout << x << "\n";
    std::cout << y << "\n";
    std::cout << z << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: “C++ is typed” — so is Python; the difference is that it’d dynamically rather than statically typed, (and the `list` type by default accepts `Any` rather than a more constrained type). But you’re right about the dangers of attempting verbatim translations across very different languages.

Comment: You are right python is dynamically typed (which usually means you will find errors at runtime instead of compile time).